# Selective SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 3 tables, `Items`, `FileLinks` and `Files`, where each Item can have multiple files associated with it.

Items has ItemID and ItemName.

FileLinks is a link table between Items and Files containing ItemID and FileID.

Files has FileID, FileURL and FileCategory.

I would like a query that lists all Items (no duplicates) and the URL of the single file of a specified category with a blank in the URL field if there is no file of that category.

I started with this:

```
select items.itemid, items.itemname, files.url
from items
inner join filelinks on items.itemid = filelinks.itemid
inner join files on filelinks.fileid = files.fileid
where files.filecategory = 1
```

But that only shows items that have a file of that category and hides those that dont as well as duplicating the items list if there are multiple files per item. I need ALL items, and only the single file that is in that category or a blank.

Sample Data:

```
items
ItemID ItemName
1     apple
2     orange

filelinks
itemid fileid
1 1
1 2 
2 3
2 4

files
fileid category url
1     main apple.jpg
2     secondary apple2.jpg
3     main orange.jpg
4     secondary orange2.jpg

if category = main, then results should be

itemid itemname url
1      apple    apple.jpg
2      orange   orange.jpg
```

Comment: SQL Server 2014, tag added

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN instead if inner join.

Comment: LEFT JOIN still seems to give me the duplication if there are multiple files per item (the item appears twice in the list)

Comment: You have one to many relation but you want to get one to one. How do you define which FileURL should be returned for particular item if there are multiple files in this category for this item ?

Comment: Then you have to decide how to chose files. And tell us!

Comment: Thats a fair point, the data only ever has one file per category but I guess a firstordefault type should be used

Comment: @Al.G., perhaps that's what OP wants, hard to tell. But I'll give it a try!

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes I'm after reducing my one to many to a one to one based on the category. I'm happy returning the first "hit" based on the category as the data should only have one listing for that category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `LEFT JOIN`'s to also get items without any filelinks or files:

```
select items.itemid, items.itemname, files.url
from items
left join filelinks on items.itemid = filelinks.itemid
left join files on filelinks.fileid = files.fileid
               and files.filecategory = 1
```

To only get one file for an item, do a `GROUP BY` and pick the `MIN` one:

```
select items.itemid, items.itemname, MIN(files.url)
from items
left join filelinks on items.itemid = filelinks.itemid
left join files on filelinks.fileid = files.fileid
               and files.filecategory = 1
group by items.itemid, items.itemname
```